# Spring Boot repository save does not work (only shows a select)

Tags: spring-boot, insert, spring-data-jpa, composite-key

I'm facing for hours with a strange proceeding in Spring Boot when try to save a mapped entity.

The entity class with a composite key that must all be set by the user is as follows:

```
package model

import javax.persistence.*

@Entity
@Table(name = 'MY_TABLE')
@IdClass(MyIdClass.class)
class MyClass implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @Column(name = "MY_COLUMN_1")
    Long column1

    @Id
    @Column(name = "MY_COLUMN_2")
    Long column2

    @Id
    @Column(name = "MY_COLUMN_3")
    String column3

    @Id
    @Column(name = "MY_COLUMN_4")
    Date date1

    @Column(name = "MY_COLUMN_5")
    Date date2

    @Column(name = "MY_COLUMN_6")
    BigDecimal column6
}

@Embeddable
class MyIdClass implements Serializable{
    Long column1
    Long column2
    String column3
    Date date1;
}
```

The corresponding repository is:

```
package repository

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository

interface MyRepository extends CrudRepository<MyClass, Long>{
}
```

My service is:

```
package service

import model.MyClass
import repository.MyRepository
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service

@Service
class MyService {

    @Autowired
    MyRepository repository

    void save(MyClass myClass) {
        repository.save(myClass)
    }
}
```

My controller mounts a MyClass object with all data set, including the composite key. When it calls the service save method the object is not inserted in the database. I saw the logs and checked that there is a SELECT in MY_TABLE instead of INSERT. I tried not to inform the composite key in the object and then the save method did an INSERT with error due to null values in the primary key.

I really don't understand why the insertion is not done when the composite key has values. How can I solve it?

I've already tried with @Transactional in service class and didn't work. I didn't do any Transaction configuration in the project since Spring Boot delivers it as default.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take your code sample and tried it on a sample Spring Boot project, where I was able to save to H2 DB (In memory) with `@Embeddable` & `@EmbeddedId` annotations. If you would like to verify, you can clone the GitHub repo and run the `BootJpaApplication.java` as a Java Application.
After execution access the H2 console with the below link from local where table details can be verified.

http://localhost:8080/h2-console
[image]
https://github.com/sujittripathy/springboot-sample.git

Hope the detail helps:)

Answer (score 4):

It seems you are using `MyIdClass` as the Id for `MyClass`. So, the Repository should be:

```
interface MyRepository extends CrudRepository<MyClass, MyIdClass>{
}
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Kenny. It was a lack of attention, indeed. I changed the MyRepository to use MyIdClass, but nothing changed. The object is not inserted into the database and the log remains to show only SELECT.

Comment: And can you try to replace the @IdClass to use @EmbeddedId?!

Comment: @Fabrizio where to annotate EmbeddedId on column variable?